# Don't working vertical alignment of img in div css

Tags: html, css

In my web site I have blocks that describe site features. In this block there are div element which contains img, and I want to align the image vertically in middle of the div, but my code don't working. My html code -

```
<div class="col-3 feature_block">
    <div><img src="{{ URL::asset('pic/services1.svg') }}"/></div>
    <h4>Işiň awtomatizasiýasy</h4>
    <p>Awtomatlaşdyrylan proses ullanyjynyň ulgama giren badyna başlaýar.</p>
</div>
```

My css code -

```
.feature_block div{
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    margin: 25px 0 25px 0;
    background-color: white;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 80px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

What happens in browser -
[screenshot of browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/anxMo.png)

Please help, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
.feature_block div{
display:flex;
justify-content:center;
align-items:center;
}
```

Comment: Yes, it works, thank you. I hearead about display: flex but did't use it. flex - new value of css3, or it was before?

Comment: Yes, new value of CSS3

Answer (score 0):

Your class name is **col-3**.
So your CSS should be like this :

```
 .col-3 div {
   ....
  }
```